# How to loop through an array in pug?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to loop through an array (the `array` is `c`) in pug, using `javascript` for loop, but can't seem to understand how to pass the `JS` variable `x` to the pug code. I've tried `#{"x"}, !{"x"}` and a few more.

This is my pug `code` :

```
-var x
-for (x=0; x<3; x++){
        .youtube-container
            iframe(width='420', height='345', src=c[#{"x"}].youtubeURL)
            div
                img(src='./images/chatsnip.PNG', alt='chat')
                h3#demo
                p
                |    sales culture is collaborative with a
                br
                |    healthy dose of competitive spirit.
-}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute values are evaluated as JavaScript, and need not be followed by commas, so you can say:

```
iframe(width='420' height='345' src=x.youtubeURL)
```

I would suggest you use `each` instead of iterating manually:

```
each x in c
  .youtube-container
    iframe(width='420' height='345' src=x.youtubeURL)
      div
        img(src='./images/chatsnip.PNG', alt='chat')
        h3#demo
        p
        |    sales culture is collaborative with a
        br
        |    healthy dose of competitive spirit.
```